# @OrderColumn failing to sort arraylist by order of insertion

Tags: jpa

Need ArrayList to hold Objects by the order it was saved to database. Using @OrderColumn to achieve this but for some reason it's failing to sort by first to last.

The following Test saves 2 objects and attempts to retrieve the objects in descending order (see last line) which fails.

```
Watching.class

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
      targetEntity = Ticker.class,
      fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name="watching_ticker",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="watching_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="ticker_id"))
  @OrderBy("id desc")
  private List<Ticker> tickers;

...

Ticker.class
  @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name ="watching_ticker",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="ticker_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "watching_id"))
  protected Set<Watching> watchings;

..

Tester

Account account;
AccountService accountService;
    Ticker ticker;
    Ticker tickerTwo;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    account = ...
        ticker = ...;
      tickerTwo = ...;
    ....
    }

  @Test
  public void testSave() {

    Watching watching = account.getWatching();
    watching.getTickers().add(ticker);
    watching.getTickers().add(tickerTwo);


    Watching saved = accountService.save(account).getWatching();


    Ticker one = saved.getTickers().get(0);
    int size = saved.getTickers().size();
    assertEquals(2, size);
    Assert.assertEquals(one, tickerTwo); <-- fails
  }
```

Comment: That does not track insertion order but order in (POJO) array. Both can be very different.

Comment: You should be able to connect the dots here. Keep persist order as in array and you will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Use @OrderBy instead. @OrderColumn orders records by a non visible column other than ID.

> The order column is not visible as part of the state of the entity or
>   embeddable class.
>
> The OrderBy annotation should be used for ordering that is visible as
>   persistent state and maintained by the application.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html

Comment: arraylist still does not hold objects in order. @OrderBy("id ASC") (id primary key in join table)

Comment: Did you used javax.persistence.OrderBy ?

Comment: Set does not support sort. Besides I think OrderBy and OrderColumn do different things. Think I need OrderColumn.

Comment: Can I see the Test Class - save and retrieval

Comment: List was being modified elsewhere. @OrderColumn works fine.

Comment: please delete your answer so I can remove this post as it is misleading.

Comment: Study https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html. Id is visible part of entity, i.e. OrderBy should be used.

Comment: If it works it does not mean that it is used as it should.

Comment: OrderBy is not displaying the contents in correct order for me (I don't know why). @OrderColumn seems to sort items in correct order.

Comment: Post whole code of Entity in question. Perhaps something is wrong there.